# Random space in table that I can't seem to change or remove

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm trying to format a table where I have an image in the first column and a description in the second column, but when I started replacing the placeholder images, I discovered a random gap between the image and the edge of the first column. I've tried everything I can think of to get rid of it but nothing seems to work, what am I doing wrong?

```css
.table1 {
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing:0;
  color: #1e919e;
}

.table1 a {
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  color: #c755c5;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Sofia", sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  border: 2px solid #c755c5;
  border-radius: 24px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.table1 a:hover {
  background-color: #46464677;
  border-radius: 24px;
  border: 2px solid #823ab9;
  color: #823ab9;
}
.table1 img {
  float: left;
  width: 63%;
}

.description {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table1" width="75%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="switchon.png" />
    </td>
    <td class="description">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
       consectetur adipiscing elit. <br>
       Nunc feugiat augue ac tellus <br>
       sagittis sagittis. Fusce <br>
       faucibus nisi sit amet metus <br>
       varius euismod. Nam commodo <br>
       ligula vel arcu porttitor <br>
       laoreet. Morbi ac. <br> <be>
       <a href="crime.html">Click me</a>
     </td>
   </tr>
```

[Image of what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3ymz.png)

Comment: What is `<be>` here?  `laoreet. Morbi ac. <br> <be>`

Comment: the <be> is an error (supposed to be another <br>) but its not like that in the original code, looks like my computer auto-corrected it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using a `width: 63%;` on your `table1 img` styles. This is saying you only want your image to use up `63%` of the space available in the column, hence, the white space. Change it to 100% so it uses all the space. See the CSS changes I made below.

```css
.table1 {
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing:0;
  color: #1e919e;
}

.table1 a {
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  color: #c755c5;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Sofia", sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  border: 2px solid #c755c5;
  border-radius: 24px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.table1 a:hover {
  background-color: #46464677;
  border-radius: 24px;
  border: 2px solid #823ab9;
  color: #823ab9;
}
.table1 img {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

td > img {
  width: 25%;
}

td.description {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<table class="table1" width="75%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/000/fff" />
    </td>
    <td class="description">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
       consectetur adipiscing elit. <br>
       Nunc feugiat augue ac tellus <br>
       sagittis sagittis. Fusce <br>
       faucibus nisi sit amet metus <br>
       varius euismod. Nam commodo <br>
       ligula vel arcu porttitor <br>
       laoreet. Morbi ac. <br> <be>
       <a href="crime.html">Click me</a>
     </td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: Ohhhh that makes sense, thank you! What and where should I put something to keep the image fixed to the size it is? Just in the <img> tag?

Comment: @LizyBee What do you mean by "keep the image fixed to the size it is"?

Comment: When I remove the width, the image gets bigger to fill the space but I wanted the image to stay the same size and have the row with the text to essentially move over, do I add something to the img tag to define the size or would it make more sense to add something to the table1 style?

Comment: You can set a width on your `td.description` to make the description move over. Essentially just declare the width on that class. For example, in the updated answer I made the image column 25% width and the description column 75% width. See the updated answer!